# Box2d jitter when camera follows

Tags: android, opengl-es, box2d

I am developing a box2d game on android and when the opengl camera follows the player the player jitters quite badly. When the camera is stationary, it appears to be fine. I tried box2d interpolation and that seemed to help slightly. Any suggestions?

```
public static void setCamera() {

    // Position the eye behind the origin.
    float eyeX = cameraX;
    float eyeY = cameraY;
    float eyeZ = cameraZoom;

    // We are looking toward the distance
    float lookX = cameraX;
    float lookY = cameraY;
    float lookZ = -5.0f;

    // Set our up vector. This is where our head would be pointing were we
    // holding the camera.
    float upX = 0.0f;
    float upY = 1.0f;
    float upZ = 0.0f;

    // Set the view matrix. This matrix can be said to represent the camera
    // position.
    // NOTE: In OpenGL 1, a ModelView matrix is used, which is a combination
    // of a model and
    // view matrix. In OpenGL 2, we can keep track of these matrices
    // separately if we choose.
    Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, eyeX, eyeY, eyeZ, lookX, lookY,
            lookZ, upX, upY, upZ);
    // Matrix.scaleM(mViewMatrix, 0, cameraZoom, cameraZoom, 0f);

    // Matrix.orthoM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, left, right, top, bottom, near,
    // far);
    // Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, 1, 0, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f,
    // 0.0f);
}
```

Comment: Code for the camera movement implemented would be helpful.

Comment: @mrVoid I edited my original post

Comment: I do not see anything of the camera movement logic in this code. The problem you are experiencing is probably due to physics/camera sync update disparity. This might be fixed by a follow algorithm for the camera. But still need some relevant code snippet to write something of use.